# Convert a dataframe to a list of lists based on common features

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large data frame which I would like to transform into a list of lists. The lists would be split by the column names of the data frame. 
The data frame looks like this.

```
df1 <- data.frame(TP1.expression =c(3, 8, 2),
                  TP1.pval = c(0.04, 0.03, 0.01),
                  TP1.log2fc = c(1, 0.3, 2.1),
                  TP2.expression =c(2, 4, 2.1),
                  TP2.pval = c(0.024, 0.02, 0.01),
                  TP2.log2fc = c(-1, 0.1, 3.1),
                  row.names = c('GeneA', 'GeneB', 'GeneC'))
```

I would like to transform `df1` into a list of lists. The list structure would ideally be as followed.

```
list1
   TP1
      TP1.expression       3, 8, 2
      TP1.pval             0.04, 0.03, 0.01
      TP1.log2fc           1, 0.3, 2.1
   TP2
      TP2.expression       2, 4, 2.1
      TP2.pval             0.024, 0.02, 0.01
      TP2.log2fc           -1, 0.1, 3.1
```

So the list would split be the integer found between `TP` and the `.` characters.

I have managed to split the data frame into smaller data frames and the re-combined these into a list but the method used was too specific. I am looking for something more generic to turn into a function.

The example below will seperate df1 into five different data frames which can then be re-sorted into a list. I am looking for cleaner ways of doing this.

```
tp <- c(1, 2, 3, 10, 14)
timepoint <- 'TP'
for (i in tp) {
  common <- paste0(timepoint, i)
  assign(common, df1[, grep(paste0(common, "\\."),   colnames(df1), ignore.case = T)])
  X <- list(TP1, TP2, TP3, TP10, TP14)
}
```

Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `split.default` to split the columns based on names of the dataframe and then use `as.list` to create lists of list.

```
lapply(split.default(df1, sub("(TP\\d+).*", "\\1", names(df1))), as.list)

#$TP1
#$TP1$TP1.expression
#[1] 3 8 2

#$TP1$TP1.pval
#[1] 0.04 0.03 0.01

#$TP1$TP1.log2fc
#[1] 1.0 0.3 2.1


#$TP2
#$TP2$TP2.expression
#[1] 2.0 4.0 2.1

#$TP2$TP2.pval
#[1] 0.024 0.020 0.010

#$TP2$TP2.log2fc
#[1] -1.0  0.1  3.1
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks this worked very well. Could you please explain what \\d+ and \\1 do?

Comment: @Krutik it extracts `"TP"` followed by a digit. Check `sub("(TP\\d+).*", "\\1", names(df1))`